# Imagemagick -subimage-search command hanging

Tags: windows, command, imagemagick

```
compare.exe -metric RMSE -subimage-search screenshot.png locator.png null
```

This command just hangs and runs my CPU at 13% until I press Ctrl + C

Other compare commands are working just fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option '[-subimage-search](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#subimage-search.)' searches for the second image at EVERY possible location in the first image. This is slow! very very slow.. When you have large images this can take a lot of minutes to complete. With the option '-debug all' you can see what is happening but this will make the process even slower.

Comment: When I let it run, it did end up finishing after a minute. I think I'll use a different algorithm then, I don't need something so brute force. ty